# Json Data Acess

Tags: javascript, json

I have below json data in the variable .

```
var links = {
  info: {
   title: "Informatics "

  },
  busi: {
   title: "Business"

  },
  lang: {
   title: "Language"

  }
};
```

In the code i have the variable named type which could have string as info,busi,lang and that variable is getting as a function argument like

```
function get_data(type)
 {
    var data = JSON.parse(links);
    // Now i want to access the title of that particular type only I tried to use this but it didnt work 
    // data.type 
    // where as if i use the exact word it shows me data like this data.info 
  }
```

I want to make the code more generalize rather than sticking to constants like info, busi ,land . Any suggestions how can i make it more generalize ?

Comment: Please note that your problem has nothing to do with JSON. A JavaScript is not the same as JSON.

Comment: Related: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reference dynamic property names, rather than statically, you need square bracket, not dot, syntax.

`data.type` - looks for a property named 'type'

`data[type]` - looks for a property whose name is contained within a variable `type`

Comment: Thanks , it worked !

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer, in this case.